# apt Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies, dist-upgrade

i was tring to update Debian with the instruction
https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#upgrade-process
All going well but when i ran

```
apt full-upgrade
```

ssh session was interrupted, message was:

```
Unpacking libkf5plasmaquick5:amd64 (5.103.0-1) over (5.78.0-3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../50-libgl1_1.6.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1:amd64 (1.6.0-1) over (1.3.2-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../51-libglx0_1.6.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglx0:amd64 (1.6.0-1) over (1.3.2-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../52-libopengl0_1.6.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libopengl0:amd64 (1.6.0-1) over (1.3.2-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../53-milou_4%3a5.27.5-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking milou (4:5.27.5-2) over (4:5.20.5-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../54-breeze-cursor-theme_4%3a5.27.5-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking breeze-cursor-theme (4:5.27.5-2) over (4:5.20.5-4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../55-libkf5style5_5.103.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkf5style5:amd64 (5.103.0-1) over (5.78.0-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-xtUF3X/22-software-properties-qt_0.99.30-4_all.deb
Log ended: 2023-06-12  16:28:58
```

after some time connection was restored and now when i try to run any command i get:

```
sudo apt reinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 breeze : Depends: kde-style-breeze (= 4:5.27.5-2) but 4:5.20.5-4 is installed
          Depends: libkf5kcmutils5 (>= 5.102.0~) but 5.78.0-3 is installed
          Recommends: kde-style-qtcurve but it is not installable
 dbus : Depends: dbus-daemon (= 1.14.6-1) but it is not installed
        Depends: dbus-system-bus-common (>= 1.14.6-1) but it is not installed
 dbus-user-session : Depends: dbus-daemon (= 1.14.6-1) but it is not installed or
                              dbus-broker but it is not installed
 dbus-x11 : Depends: dbus-daemon (= 1.14.6-1) but it is not installed
 dmsetup : Depends: libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.181) but 2:1.02.175-2.1 is installed
 eog : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-20 (>= 3.17.92) but it is not installed
 evince : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-20 (>= 3.17.92) but it is not installed
 evolution-data-server : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.1.1) but it is not installed
 gdm3 : Depends: dbus-daemon but it is not installed
 geoclue-2.0 : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.3) but it is not installed
 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-20 (>= 43~alpha) but it is not installed
 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 : Depends: libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 (= 2.40.1-1) but 2.40.1-1~deb11u1 is installed
 gir1.2-rest-1.0 : Depends: librest-1.0-0 (>= 0.9.1) but it is not installed
 gir1.2-shumate-1.0 : Depends: gir1.2-gtk-4.0 but it is not installed
 gir1.2-soup-3.0 : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (= 3.2.2-2) but it is not installed
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (= 2.40.1-1) but 2.40.1-1~deb11u1 is installed
 gnome-calculator : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 2.41.90) but it is not installed
 gnome-characters : Depends: gir1.2-gtk-4.0 (>= 4.6) but it is not installed
                    Depends: gir1.2-adw-1 (>= 1.2~alpha) but it is not installed
 gnome-control-center : Depends: libgoa-backend-1.0-1 (>= 3.45) but 3.38.0-3 is installed
                        Depends: libnma-gtk4-0 (>= 1.8.34) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libsnapd-glib-2-1 (>= 1.63) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libwacom9 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not installed
                        Recommends: gnome-remote-desktop (>= 42) but it is not installed
                        Recommends: power-profiles-daemon but it is not installed
                        Recommends: network-manager-gnome (>= 0.9.8) but it is not installed
 gnome-online-accounts : Depends: libgoa-backend-1.0-1 (= 3.46.0-1) but 3.38.0-3 is installed
                         Depends: librest-1.0-0 (>= 0.9.1-2) but it is not installed
 gnome-session-bin : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-20 (>= 3.34.2) but it is not installed
 gnome-settings-daemon : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-20 (>= 3.37.1) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libwacom9 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not installed
 gnome-shell : Depends: gir1.2-adw-1 but it is not installed
               Depends: gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-3.0 (>= 42.3) but it is not installed
               Depends: gir1.2-gtk-4.0 but it is not installed
               Depends: gir1.2-mutter-11 (>= 43.0) but it is not installed
               Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-20 (>= 3.35.90) but it is not installed
               Recommends: gnome-remote-desktop but it is not installed
               Recommends: power-profiles-daemon but it is not installed
 gnome-shell-extension-prefs : Depends: gir1.2-adw-1 but it is not installed
                               Depends: gir1.2-gtk-4.0 but it is not installed
 gnome-shell-extensions : Depends: gir1.2-adw-1 but it is not installed
                          Depends: gir1.2-gtk-4.0 but it is not installed
 gnome-software : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.3) but it is not installed
 gnome-weather : Depends: gir1.2-adw-1 (>= 1.2~alpha) but it is not installed
                 Depends: gir1.2-gtk-4.0 (>= 4.5) but it is not installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: libdirectfb-1.7-7 (>= 1.7.7) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libfluidsynth3 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installed
                            Depends: liblrdf0 (>= 0.4.0-1.2) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libneon27 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libopenh264-7 (>= 2.3.1+dfsg) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libzxing2 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installed
 gvfs-backends : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.3) but it is not installed
 gvfs-fuse : Depends: libfuse3-3 (>= 3.12.0) but 3.10.3-2 is installed
 kde-config-screenlocker : Depends: libkf5configqml5 (>= 5.94.0) but it is not installed
                           Depends: libkf5kcmutils5 (>= 5.102.0~) but 5.78.0-3 is installed
 kwin-common : Depends: libinput10 (>= 1.19.1) but 1.16.4-3 is installed
               Depends: libkdecorations2private10 (>= 4:5.27.5~) but it is not installed
               Depends: libkf5kcmutils5 (>= 5.102.0~) but 5.78.0-3 is installed
               Depends: libkf5kcmutilscore5 (>= 5.102.0~) but it is not installed
               Depends: libkf5newstuffcore5 (>= 5.102.0~) but 5.78.0-4 is installed
               Depends: libkf5newstuffwidgets5 (>= 5.102.0~) but it is not installed
               Depends: libkwineffects14 (= 4:5.27.5-3) but it is not installed
               Depends: libkwinglutils14 (= 4:5.27.5-3) but it is not installed
               Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
               Recommends: plasma-desktop (>= 4:5.27.5~) but 4:5.20.5-4 is installed
 kwin-style-breeze : Depends: kde-style-breeze (= 4:5.27.5-2) but 4:5.20.5-4 is installed
 kwin-x11 : Depends: libkwineffects14 (= 4:5.27.5-3) but it is not installed
            Depends: libkwinglutils14 (= 4:5.27.5-3) but it is not installed
 libedata-book-1.2-27 : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.1.1) but it is not installed
 libedata-cal-2.0-2 : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.1.1) but it is not installed
 libedataserver-1.2-27 : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.1.1) but it is not installed
 libedataserverui-1.2-4 : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.1.1) but it is not installed
 libedataserverui4-1.0-0 : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.1.1) but it is not installed
 libegl-mesa0 : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 22.3.6-1+deb12u1) but 20.3.5-1 is installed
 libevolution : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-20 (>= 3.17.92) but it is not installed
                Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.1) but it is not installed
 libgeocode-glib-2-0 : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.3) but it is not installed
 libgl1 : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.6.0-1) but 1.3.2-1 is installed
 libglx0 : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.6.0-1) but 1.3.2-1 is installed
 libgnome-desktop-4-2 : Depends: gnome-desktop3-data (>= 43.2-2) but 3.38.5-3 is installed
 libgnome-rr-4-2 : Depends: gnome-desktop3-data (>= 43.2-2) but 3.38.5-3 is installed
 libgweather-4-0 : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.3) but it is not installed
 libkdecorations2-5v5 : Depends: libkdecorations2private10 (= 4:5.27.5-2) but it is not installed
 libkf5auth5 : Depends: libkf5auth-data (= 5.103.0-1) but 5.78.0-2 is installed
 libkf5authcore5 : Depends: libkf5auth-data (= 5.103.0-1) but 5.78.0-2 is installed
 libkf5iconthemes5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
                     Recommends: libkf5iconthemes-bin (= 5.103.0-1) but 5.78.0-2 is installed
 libkf5waylandclient5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libkf5xmlgui5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
                 Recommends: libkf5xmlgui-bin (= 5.103.0-1) but 5.78.0-2 is installed
 libkscreenlocker5 : Depends: libkf5configqml5 (>= 5.94.0) but it is not installed
                     Depends: libkf5screendpms8 (>= 4:5.26.90) but it is not installed
                     Depends: liblayershellqtinterface5 (>= 5.27.5~) but it is not installed
 libmutter-11-0 : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-20 (>= 3.36.0) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libinput10 (>= 1.19.1) but 1.16.4-3 is installed
                  Depends: libwacom9 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not installed
 libopengl0 : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.6.0-1) but 1.3.2-1 is installed
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 252.6-1) but 247.3-7+deb11u2 is installed
 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 : Depends: libpulse0 (= 16.1+dfsg1-2+b1) but 14.2-2 is installed
 libqt5dbus5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5designer5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5network5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5positioning5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5printsupport5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5qml5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5qmlmodels5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5quick5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5quickcontrols2-5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
                          Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5quickparticles5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5quicktemplates2-5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
                           Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5quickwidgets5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5sensors5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5sql5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5sql5-sqlite : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5svg5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
              Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5test5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5texttospeech5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
                       Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5waylandclient5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
                        Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5waylandcompositor5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
                            Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5webchannel5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
                     Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5webkit5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5widgets5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libqt5x11extras5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
 libqt5xml5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 libshumate-1.0-1 : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.3) but it is not installed
 libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0 : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.3) but it is not installed
 libwebkitgtk-6.0-4 : Depends: libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.3) but it is not installed
 plasma-pa : Depends: pulseaudio but it is not installed
 pulseaudio-module-gsettings : Depends: pulseaudio (= 14.2-2) but it is not installed
 python3-pyqt5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 qml-module-qt-labs-platform : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
                               Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
 qml-module-qtquick-controls : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
                               Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 qml-module-qtquick-controls2 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
                                Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
                              Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 qml-module-qtquick-layouts : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
                                     Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 qml-module-qtquick-templates2 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
 qtwayland5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.8+dfsg~) but 5.15.2+dfsg-9 is installed
              Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
 software-properties-common : Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.99.30-4) but 0.96.20.2-2.1 is installed
 xdg-desktop-portal-gnome : Depends: xdg-desktop-portal (>= 1.15.0) but 1.8.1-1 is installed
 xdg-desktop-portal-kde : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-15-8
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

is there any solution .... ?

upd:
Not any methods were helped. I just install Debian 12 from scratch.
thanks to all

Comment: try running `dpkg --configure --pending` and then run `apt full-upgrade` again. You should not need to run `apt reinstall`, that apt sub-command is for when you want to re-install an already installed package.

Comment: ``dpkg --configure --pending``
output
``sudo dpkg --configure --pending
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-calculator:
 gnome-calculator depends on libsoup-3.0-0 (>= 2.41.90); however:
  Package libsoup-3.0-0 is not installed.
 gnome-calculator depends on dconf-gsettings-backend | gsettings-backend; however:
  Package dconf-gsettings-backend:amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package gsettings-backend is not installed.
...

Processing was halted because there were too many errors.``

Comment: yes, it can take multiple runs of `dpkg --configure --pending` followed by `apt full-upgrade` to get the packaging system back in to a good state.  If you get to a point where this sequence of commands no longer helps (i.e. nothing changes when you run them again), try the `apt-get -f install` suggested by the error message or `apt-get -f full-upgrade` and **very carefully** examine what it proposes to install and/or remove.  If you have no objections to what it wants to do, go ahead with it then return to the `dpkg --configure -pending; apt-get full-upgrade` cycle.  Repeat as needed.

Comment: BTW if, when examining the `-f` output, you notice that the upgrade is being blocked by one or more packages, then you can attempt to clear the blocking yourself - by installing or removing the offending package(s) with `dpkg` or sometimes with `apt`.   Also note: there is no one magic command that will fix all problems caused by a crash (or loss of the ssh session) during an upgrade as there are far too many variables (mainly the number of packages installed and to be installed or removed). Fixing it requires fairly deep knowledge of the packaging system and how it works.

Comment: For example, try `apt-get -f install libsoup-3.0-0` and carefully examine the output. If it doesn't want to uninstall things you need to keep installed, then accept what it proposes to do.

Comment: BTW, don't post output from commands into a comment.  That results in an unreadable mess.  Hardly anyone will even bother to read it.  Edit your question and add the output there (and format it as text)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error this week, when trying to upgrade my 2 Debian virtual machines, both running KDE as desktop environment.

What did fix it for me was, running first:

```
dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-qt_0.99.30-4_all.deb
```

This **did** install the above package but ended up in a few other errors.

I followed up with:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

And then with:

```
apt full-upgrade
```

At this stage I had a fully upgraded OS (i.e. no more warnings or errors when re-running `apt full-upgrade`).

I followed up with this, to get rid of older unused packages:

```
apt --purge autoremove
```

However, if you're actually using the KDE DE, you may discover that for some reason at this stage, the upgrade may still leave you with a broken KDE desktop environment. Namely:

1. On the first VM, after reboot, as soon as the system reached the graphical target, I was getting a black screen that wouldn't respond to any key combo. I had to reboot to an older kernel and choose Gnome DE to enter a graphical environment.
2. On the second VM, I got to the login screen but only Gnome DE choices were available; no KDE.

So, to avoid this last snag you can just reinstall KDE **before reboot**:

```
apt install task-kde-desktop
```

P.S. If you skipped this last step and hit the problem with KDE broken, you'll probably have to reinstall it after you reboot and re-enter your system somehow, either via an alternative DE that may have been previously installed (like I did) or else by choosing on the GRUB menu --> Advanced Options --> Recovery Mode and then once you're logged into a `runlevel 1` session by switching to `runlevel 3` with `systemctl isolate multi-user.target`. Since there you get network access which will allow you to install whatever packages you're missing.

Comment: Thank you very much; saved my upgrade today!